# Reflection. How come java's static type system can allow you not knowing an object type at compile time?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to find some useful cases for reflection on my own and i've just discovered an interesting thought from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) post:
it says,

> say you have an object of an unknown type in Java

Can you provide a couple of examples of that with a plain English explanation?

Comment: For example, if you want to write a method which serializes any `Object` to `json`  or `xml`

Comment: Unknown type such as you only know it `extends Object` but don't know what it is.

Comment: Oh yes, makes sense. i was overthinking this badly.